# How to count number Array which inside of another Array

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have an Array like this:

```
print_r($request_params);

Array ( 
    [chat_id] => 120613381 
    [text] => Array ( 
        [0] => saadat 
        [1] => saadat 
        [2] => saadat 
        [3] => saadat 
        [4] => saadat 
        [5] => saadat 
        [6] => donya 
        [7] => donya 
        [8] => donya 
        [9] 
    )
)
```

As you can see inside of `[text]` I have multiple values. Now I want to count that but I don't know how to access that part.

My try was this but it returns 0:

```
echo $num3 = count($request_params[2]["text"]);
```

So what is your suggest..

Comment: There's no `$request_params[2]`. Just `$request_params['chat_id']` and `$request_params['text']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `[2]`:

```
echo count($request_params['text']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `array_count_values`.
It will return an associative array with the count of each name.

```
$counts = array_count_values($request_params['text']);
Var_dump($counts);
```

This should return for example:
[saadat] => 6
[donya] => 3

Comment: @slajostealos Andreas is reasonably confused here.  Please improve your question to express your desired output. (for the sake of all future SO readers)